# Why does my Python print statement keep getting repeated?

Tags: python

Sorry guys total newbie here, but I am inputting this code

```
x = 10
while x > 5:
    print(x)
    x = x-1
    print("Blastoff")
```

and whenever i run it, it prints

```
10
Blastoff
9
Blastoff
8
Blastoff
7
Blastoff
6
Blastoff
```

Process finished with exit code 0

How do I get it to countdown the numbers only, then get it to say blastoff once `x > 5`?

Comment: By putting the `print` *after* the loop.

Comment: Whats your desired outcome? Blastoff after the number 1 got printed or after x is bigger than 5?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, You need to get 5 iterations? `while x >= 5`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can achieve the desired output using a for-loop?

If you want all numbers that are `x > 5` to be saying "Blastoff" instead of the number you would use this snippet:

```py
x = 10

for i in range(10):
    x = x-1
    if x > 5:
        print("Blastoff")
    else:
        print(x)
```

If you want to print both the number *and* "Blastoff" for numbers that are `x > 5` you would use this snippet:

```py
x = 10

for i in range(10):
    x = x-1
    print(x)
    
    if x > 5:
        print("Blastoff")
```

I think that is what you are trying to achieve, right?

Comment: I just wanted the code to execute as follows (5,4,3,2,1,Blastoff) and yours did not work :( it keeps saying blastoff after every number. Wanted the numbers to countdown then once x>5 it would say blastoff.